# Which code should I use to provide the ID to another StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to give the ID to another `StatelessWidget`. But, there is two way for me to choose.

The first way is to use the model's ID. The data for this model comes from a Firebase Cloud Firestore document and I use the original ID as the document id.

The second way is to use the original ID.

Which way should I choose?

My code:

```dart
class Model {
  Model(this.id, …);

  final String id;
  …

  factory Model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentId) {
    …

    return Model(documentId, …);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {…};
}

class AccountScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AccountScreen({required this.id, super.key});

  final String id; // Original ID

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return … // Widget for getting data from a Firebase Cloud Firestore document and converting it into a model.
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Account")),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(16.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Summary",
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            onTap: () => …, // Pass the ID to another StatelessWidget
                            title: const Text(
                              "Profile",
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0),
                            ),
                            trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.cyan),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Should I use `model.id` or `id`?

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you should consider these points:**

1. If you need to use other properties from the model (may be like name, address etc.) then you should pass the model
2. If you need only the id property from the model then you should pass the id only
3. If you think, in future you will need other properties then you should pass the model property obviously. In this approach you don't have to worry about future changes/refactor.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I just pass the ID to another `StatelessWidget` which does the same thing there (gets data from Firebase Cloud Firestore document and converts it to a model). So, as you said, I should pass the original ID to the `StatelessWidget` right?

Comment: If you just need the id only then obviously you should pass the id only (but keep in mind the above 3rd point).